# complex query: using select, orderby and whereby clauses based on filters in laravel5.4?

Tags: search, filter, laravel-5.4, laravel-query-builder

I am writing code for filter search where user selects atleast one option from a list of 3 checkboxes then I have to write a query for the selected options(checkboxes). If I try to run my code then I am getting the 'RECURSION' error like below:

```
Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder Object ( [connection] => Illuminate\Database\MySqlConnection Object ( [pdo:protected] => PDO Object ( ) [readPdo:protected] => [database:protected] => membrain [tablePrefix:protected] => [config:protected] => Array ( [driver] => mysql [host] => 127.0.0.1 [port] => 3306 [database] => membrain [username] => root [password] => [unix_socket] => [charset] => utf8mb4 [collation] => utf8mb4_unicode_ci [prefix] => [strict] => 1 [engine] => [name] => mysql ) [reconnector:protected] => Closure Object ( [this] => Illuminate\Database\DatabaseManager Object ( [app:protected] => Illuminate\Foundation\Application Object ( [basePath:protected] => C:\xampp\htdocs\membrainmain [hasBeenBootstrapped:protected] => 1 [booted:protected] => 1 [bootingCallbacks:protected] => Array ( ) [bootedCallbacks:protected] => Array ( [0] => Closure Object ( [this] => App\Providers\RouteServiceProvider Object ( [namespace:protected] => App\Http\Controllers [app:protected] => Illuminate\Foundation\Application Object *RECURSION* [defer:protected] => ) ) ) [terminatingCallbacks:protected] => Array ( )
```

My form is :

```
<form id="statistics" method="post" action="{{ action('MyController@store') }}"">
 <div class="form-group">
  <label><input type="checkbox" value="suppliers" name="suppliers">suppliers</label>
 </div>
 <div class="form-group">
  <label><input type="checkbox" value="campaign" name="campaign">campaign</label>
 </div>
 <div class="form-group">
  <label><input type="checkbox" value="clients" name="clients">clients</label>
 </div>
 <div class="form-group">
   <label for="start_date">From:</label><input type="text" name="startdate" id="startdate">
 </div>
 <div class="form-group">
   <label for="start_date">From:</label><input type="text" name="enddate" id="enddate">
 </div>
 <div class="form-group">
  <button type="submit" id="process" class="btn btn-primary submit">Run Report</button>
 </div>
</form>
```

My query is below:

```
if($request->suppliers == 'suppliers'){
            $results->leftjoin('suppliers AS s', 's.id', '=', 'l.supplier_id')
                    ->select('s.name AS Supplier')
                    ->groupBy('s.name')
                    ->orderBy('s.name');
        }
if($request->campaign == 'campaign'){
            $results->leftjoin('campaigns AS c', 'c.id', '=', 'l.campaign_id')
                    ->select('c.name AS Campaign')
                    ->groupBy('c.name')
                    ->orderBy('c.name');
        }
if($request->clients == 'clients'){
            $results->leftjoin('clients AS cl', 'cl.id', '=', 'l.client_id')
                    ->groupBy('cl.name')
                    ->orderBy('cl.name');
        }
$results->whereBetween('l.received', [$start, $end])
                ->orderBy('l.disposition')
                ->get()->toArray();
            $count = count($results);
```

I need the query to be like below:

```
$results = DB::table('lead_audit AS l')
             ->leftjoin('suppliers AS s', 's.id', '=', 'l.supplier_id')
             ->leftjoin('campaigns AS c', 'c.id', '=', 'l.campaign_id')
             ->select('s.name AS Supplier', 'c.name AS Campaign', 'l.disposition AS Disposition')
             ->whereBetween('l.received', [$start, $end])
             ->groupBy('s.name', 'c.name', 'l.disposition')
             ->orderBy('s.name')
             ->orderBy('c.name')
             ->orderBy('l.disposition')
             ->get()->toArray();
$count = count($results);
```

**UPDATE:** If I print the query then it is showing like this

```
Array ( [query] => select `s`.`name` as `Supplier` from `lead_audit` as `l` left join `suppliers` as `s` on `s`.`id` = `l`.`supplier_id` where `l`.`received` between ? and ? group by `s`.`name` order by `s`.`name` asc, `l`.`disposition` asc [bindings] => Array ( [0] => 2017-06-01 [1] => 2017-06-06 ) [time] => 1 )
```

Normal query works fine but if I write based on filters then it is not working properly. I think the query order is missing, can anyone please help me out in this. Thanks.

Comment: Recursion is not the error here, that's just part of the trace. The real error is visible on the error page. You should debug the query, see the `Listening For Query Events` section on https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/database#running-queries. Optionally you can use the `->toSql()` and `->getBindings()` methods on the builder object prior to `->get()` to see your query.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I had print the query please check my question once again I have updated it.

Comment: What did you request? Right now the query is correct when `$request->suppliers == 'suppliers'` ? That said, displaying the generated sql should help you debug your code.

Comment: 1 sidenote, when you already have a query builder and you want to add select fields, use `addSelect()` instead of `select()`, the last one will overwrite any previous selects.

Comment: Thanks I have added addSelect() for my last selection, after adding this, all the selection of the options working fine if I manually run those sql statements in phpMyAdmin. but now I am getting a different error. that is as I was using laravel-Excel package it needs only array that is why Am using "array_map" method. I got error like "array_map(): Argument #2 should be an array"

Comment: AS I mentioned in the question above the output I am getting from query is the same as 'RECURSION' but instead of that I have to get some array as a result if I print the $results as "print_r($results)". I am not getting the output as an array.